# How can I concatenate the object timestamp with the object id and pass them to the action method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following code inside my asp.net mvc view:-

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{<tr><td>

 <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="CheckBoxSelection" 
 value="@item.TMSServerID.ToString()"/> </td>
```

which will render a check-box that have the objectid as its value.
and I wrote the following script which will collect all the ids of the selected objects:-

```
var boxData = [];

        $("input[name='CheckBoxSelection']:checked").each(function () {
            boxData.push($(this).val());
        });

    }

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: URL,
             data: { ids: boxData.join(",")}
            //code goes here
```

and the action method which accept the ids looks as follow;-

```
public ActionResult TransferSelectedServers(string ids)
if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    var serverIDs = ids.Split(',');
```

now what i am trying to achieve is that i want the checkbox to contain a string that concatenate both the objectid+timestamp. currently the object id is of type int and the timestamp of type byte[].

But i have the following 2 questions:-

1.how i will convert the timestamp to a string and concatenate it with the id , such as:-

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {<tr><td>

     <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="CheckBoxSelection" 
     value="@item.TMSServerID.ToString()"+ "@item.timestamp.ToString()"/> </td>
```

2.Inside my action method how I will convert the string representing the timestamp to a byte[] again, after splitting the string?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

1) Your code for concatenating the strings is close, but you'll need to throw some kind of delimiter in there to find out where one value stops and the other begins. If the ID is an int, then you can use any non-int character for the delimiter. Something like:

```
value="@string.Format("{0},{1}", item.TMSServerID, item.timestamp)"
```

...which bring us to

2) The above won't give you what you want because byte[].ToString() will just give you "System.Byte[]". Why is the timestamp a byte[]? What format is that? Is that from SQL? My suggestion is to convert that byte[] to a `DateTime` if you can so it's more readily usable.

Once it's a `DateTime` you can just use `item.timestamp.Ticks` in your concatenation. Then it's a simple matter of your AJAX handler to do this:

```
string[] parts = ids.Split(',');
int id = int.Parse(parts[0]);
DateTime timestamp = new DateTime(long.Parse(parts[1]));
```

Comment: well the timestamp is of type timestamp inside the sql server DB. and it was mapped as byte[] when i map my tables using entity framework. so i am afraid if i chnage the type for the tiemstamp i will get into many troubles ... and the entity framework might not check for concurrency exception any more

Answer (score 1):

I always seem to stumble upon your questions John G.

**Answer to Question 1**

You're close with your concatenated attribute you're just missing the brackets around your razor syntax.

```
value="@(item.TMSServerID.ToString() + System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(@item.timestamp))"
```

**Answer to Question 2**

You need a way of splitting the string again. So you could pass over a splitting char, for example "**-**"

```
value="@(item.TMSServerID.ToString() + "-" + System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(@item.timestamp))"
```

Then you can split this in your controller

```
var serverIDs = ids.Split(',');

foreach (var serverid in serverIDs)
{
      var split = serverid.Split('-');

      var name = split[0];
      byte[] bytearray = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(split[1]);
}
```

Whilst this is a solution I would recommend binding the values you need to a model. I'm not a fan of splitting and joining strings in an application as they can cause all sorts of problems.

As such, I would recommended reading the answer @wertzui has provided.

Comment: i tried your approach , but the values passed to the action method will be such as ids "436-System.Byte[],711-System.Byte[]" and i will get an error that input string was not in a correct format. seems that the timestamp value will be system.Byte[]  and not the actual time stamp value ??

Comment: Ooh I didnt realise your timestamp was a bytearray. See my update

Comment: now i will get the bytarray value as  {byte[13]} , and i will get the same error that input string was not in a correct format..

Comment: Your error must be after the bytearray variable is initialised. I don't know what your code does after that as you havent posted it. Basically you're trying to set a string with an invalid datatype. Set a break point and step through it.

Comment: Yeah...the byte array now has 13 bytes which is the encoded timestamp. Split[1] contains the string timestamp. I don't follow what the problem is

Comment: yes you are right , but i am getting a validation exception now ;- System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException was caught
  HResult=-2146232032
  Message=Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
       at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()

Comment: OK - Wrap it in a try catch(DbEntityValidationException ex) and see what the errors are.

Comment: the exception is   ErrorMessage "The field timestamp must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '8'." string

Comment: although the time stamp field inside my model class is byte[] and not a string !!!

Comment: Has it created a timestamp column in the database? If so, you shouldn't be setting this as its handled automatically by SQL. So every time you save a record just leave the timestamp value blank and it should update it. Hope this helps

Comment: yes the record already have a timestamp, and i am assigning the timestamp value to make sure that the records send to the action method has not been modified.. also in my case i am using javascript to post the values back and i am not using the model binder.. so i have to assign the time stamp manually..

Comment: i added [Maxlenght] data annotation for the tiemstamp ,now i am not getting any validation error , but at the same time no DBUpdateconcurrency exception is being raised when two users call the same action method at the same time.. can you advice ? this is what i was trying to achieve from the beginning .

Answer (score 0):

Write a ViewModel class that contains all properties needed:

```
public class ItemClass
{
    public bool Checked {get;set;}
    public int TMSServerID {get;set;}
    public byte[] Timestamp {get;set;}
}
```

Then in your main View use a simple EditorFor, which will automatically render the collection for you:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model)
```

Have a ItemClass.cshtml in the EditorTemplates subfolder so the above EditorFor will use it:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Checked)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TMSServerID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TimeStamp)
    </td>
</tr>
```

In your js file just use serialize to serialize the form:

```
var form = $(this).parents('form');
        $.ajax({
            type: form.attr('method'),
            url: URL,
            data: form.serialize(),
        }
```

In your Controller Action then you can iterate over your collection and check for each item if it has been checked:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(Model myModel)
{
    foreach(var item in myModel)
    {
        if(item.Checked)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```